# EAV, multiple left join query optimisation

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, entity-attribute-value

Any assitance would be greatly welcomed. Pardon my ignorance however I am wondering if anyone else has had to encounter bad EAV performance issues. I have a particular query which takes a long time. What is the best way to increase the speed on this?

```
 SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT f.*, p.`timestamp`
    FROM `tObjectValues` ov
    INNER JOIN `tObjectProperties` op ON ov.`propertyId` = op.`id`
    INNER JOIN `tObjects` o ON op.`objectId` = o.`id`
    INNER JOIN `files` f ON SUBSTRING(ov.`value`, CHAR_LENGTH('cache://content//')) = f.`filename`
    LEFT JOIN `publishFiles` pf ON f.`id` = pf.`fileId`
    LEFT JOIN `publishes` p ON p.`id` = pf.`publishId` AND o.`appId` = p.`appId` AND p.`type` = 'l'
    WHERE o.`status` = 1 AND op.`status` = 1 AND ov.`status` = 1 AND ov.`value` LIKE 'cache://content/%' AND o.`appId` = 2
    ORDER BY p.`timestamp` DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10000000
) s
GROUP BY s.`id`
```

I have run the explain function to delve further into the issue however i was wondering if anyone who has had similar problem could help in the optimisation.

[image]

Comment: Functions cannot use indexes, so that might be one place to start

Comment: Also , you super query is nonsensical

Comment: I have to admit, I'm struggling to see the EAV in all of this

Comment: Thank you for answering :) Stawberry, the EAV part in this is the tObjects, tObjectProperties, tObjectValues. The structure is built around this concept so the user can add new objects in this fashion. When you say functions cannot use indexes, what do you mean by this?

Comment: `SUBSTRING(ov.value, CHAR_LENGTH...` is killing performance

Comment: Amazing ,thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if anyone else has had to encounter bad EAV performance issues.

Check out the 780 other questions tagged entity-attribute-value; most are grumbling about performance.

This discusses EAV's evils, and provide some help:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

This points out the sloppy schema being used by WP, and suggests how to improve it.  Perhaps its tips apply to your schema:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Do you really need the extra `GROUP BY` on the end?

Do you need the entire table?  It seems to be millions of rows long.